# React.JS FormControl: how to set properly default value

Tags: reactjs

I have the following Control written for `ReactJs` app. The app and the code is not written by me, but I have to modify it. However, I am new to `ReactJs`.

```
function FormSelectNative({ name, label = null, defaultValue = '', options, valueKey = 'value', labelKey = 'label', ...props }) {

  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined" size="small" fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id={name}>
        {label || name}
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        name={name}
        labelId={name}
        label={label || name}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        {...props}
      >
        {options.map(option =>
          <MenuItem key={option[valueKey]} value={option[valueKey]}>{option[labelKey]}</MenuItem>
        )}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

I need to pass `defaultValue` parameter correctly.

I am trying to set it like this:

```
         <FormSelectNative
            options={games}
            valueKey="id"
            labelKey="name"
            onChange={handleGameSelect}
            defaultValue={games[0]} 
          />
```

But it doesn't work (default value is not set). I need to set default value to be first element of "`games`". However, here I believe is some mismatch of types, so it is not set.

`Games` element example:

```
{id: 1, name: "Name of Game", description: "Some test description", helper: "test.png", created_at: "2021-08-24T16:06:13", ... some other properties}
```

Comment: `defaultValue={games[0].id}` since you are set `valueKey` as `"id"`

Comment: So, did you manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaultValue` has to be one of the possible `value` that you pass to the `MenuItem`. Each of those values is the `game.id` of each game, not the `game` object as a whole (a number, not an object). That's because you are doing `value={option[valueKey]}` where `valueKey` is `id`.

Therefore this is what you should do instead to set the default value correctly:

```
 <FormSelectNative
            options={games}
            valueKey="id"
            labelKey="name"
            onChange={handleGameSelect}
            defaultValue={games[0].id} // <<<--- get the id of the first item
          />
```